# Syntax of Foreach Statment Assistance

Tags: asp.net, foreach, syntax, razor-pages, dropdownbox

I need assistance in understanding what needs to go where in my foreach statements. Not sure that I have it correct. Could someone please take a look and explain how to "phrase" this statement?

Here is the code from my Edit.cshtml page:

```
@page
@model RabiesShotTracker1.Pages.Cases.EditModel

<form method="post">
    <input hidden asp-for="Case.Id" />
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Edit Case Information</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <h3 class="text-primary pl-3">Case Demographic Information</h3>
 
        <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Case.CaseId"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Case.CaseId" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Case.CaseId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Case.SpecieId"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Case.SpecieId" id="Select1" class="form-select">
                            <option value="">---Select Species---</option>
                            @if (Model.DisplaySpeciesData != null)
                            {
                                @foreach (var item1 in Model.DisplaySpeciesData.OrderBy(x => x.SpeciesName))
                                {
                                   <option value="@item1.SpeciesName" selected="@(item1.SpecieId==Model.Case.SpecieId?true:false)">@item1.SpeciesName</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

The SpecieId is the value that should get stored in the Case table, but the dropdown itself should display the SpeciesName for the chosen SpecieId.

Here is my .cs behind:

```
using RabiesShotTracker.Data;
using RabiesShotTracker.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RabiesShotTracker.Pages.Cases;

[BindProperties]

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Case? Case { get; set; }
    public EditModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Specie> DisplaySpeciesData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<County> DisplayCountyData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Town> DisplayTownData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TestLab> DisplayTestLabData { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int Id)
    {
        Case = _db.Case.Find(Id);
        DisplaySpeciesData = _db.Specie.ToList();
        DisplayCountyData = _db.County.ToList();
        DisplayTownData = _db.Town.ToList();
        DisplayTestLabData = _db.TestLab.ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Case.Update(Case);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Case updated successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }

}
```

Case Model in case you need that:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RabiesShotTracker.Model
{
    public class Case
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Case No")]
        public int? CaseId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Species Name")]
        public int? SpecieId { get; set; }
        public Specie? Specie { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="County Name")]
        public int? CountyId { get; set; }
        public County? County { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Town Name")]
        public int? TownId { get; set; }
        public Town? Town { get; set; }
        public string? Location { get; set; }
        public string? Notes { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Animal Captured?")]
        public string? Captured { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Captured")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? CaptureDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Animal Tested?")]
        public string? Tested { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Lab Name")]
        public int? TestLabId { get; set; }
        public TestLab? TestLab { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Diagnosed")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? DiagnosisDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Animal Rabid?")]
        public string? Rabid { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Specimen No")]
        public string? SpecimenNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Added/Updated By")]
        public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Added/Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is a snip from my Create page which works just fine.

```
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Case.SpecieId"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Case.SpecieId" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplaySpeciesData.OrderBy(x => x.SpeciesName),"SpecieId", "SpeciesName"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Species---</option></select>
                </td>
```

Here is where I am getting the null error related to the Case Model as it gets past the CaseId just fine and only has issues when it hits the dropdown field.

[image: Model Case is Null]

Just not sure why I am receiving a Null error if the syntax is correct. When I look at the database table, there are values in those fields from the records created by using the Create page. Thank you. Please ask questions if I am not describing the function clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is that you need the chunk below to be explained in plain words:

```
         @foreach (var item1 in Model.DisplaySpeciesData.OrderBy(x => x.SpeciesName))
         {
             <option value="@item1.SpeciesName" selected="@(item1.SpecieId==Model.Case.SpecieId?true:false)">@item1.SpeciesName</option>
         }
```

- `DisplaySpeciesData` is an `IEnumerable<Specie>`, that is, it's an enumerable whose elements are each a `Specie`
- I did not paste the `if` that's wrapped around the loop here, but we only reach this loop if `Model.DisplaySpeciesData` is not `null`, that is, if it was properly initialized
- we order `Model.DisplaySpeciesData` by `SpeciesName` in alphabetical order
- we loop the result, via, impersonating an element of the collection as `item1`, so, the item whose `SpeciesName` is the first in alphabetical order will be `item1` for the first time, then the second item will be `item1` until all of the items were impersonated by `item1`
- the inner block of the loop, that is, the code between `{` and `}` is the thing we aim to do for each `item1` from the collection
- So, for each item, in alphabetically ascending order by `SpeciesName` will yield an `option` tag, whose `value` is the `SpeciesName` of the current item and `selected` will have the truth value of whether `SpecieId` of the current item matches the value of `Model.Case.SpecieId`, so, if they match, then `selected` will be `true`, otherwise it will be `false`, while we show the species name in the option, so the matching item will be shown as selected in the `select` tag

EDIT

While I still do not fully understand the problem, it's possible that we just want the evaluation to be false if `Case` is `null`. In that case something like this could be the solution for the `selected` attribute:

```
selected="@((Model.Case != null) && ((item1.SpecieId==Model.Case.SpecieId))?true:false)"
```

Comment: So I have it set up correctly? That is what I was not understanding, as I am getting a Null Reference Exception when I try to run it. the "@(item1.SpecieId==Model.Case.SpecieId?true:false)" is highlighted. I wasn't sure if the issue was the setup was wrong (causing the null reference) OR if it is just that I have a null reference somewhere - which I cannot find!

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting a null exception inside the foreach? I have checked my case table and there are values in BOTH the SpecieId in the Specie Model and the Case Model.

Comment: @MelB the setup seems to be correct. But the problem is that either `item1.SpecieId` is `null` at least for one of the elements in the enumerable, or `item1` is `null` or `Model` is `null` or `Model.Case` is `null` or `Model.Case.SpecieId` is `null`. Start by changing the criterias, put in some constant instead of the `item1.SpecieId` in the comparison, so, if you still get this error, then you have an error at the right-hand side. If it works in this scenario, then you have an error at the left-hand side and only the left-hand side.

Comment: It appears that Model.Case.SpecieId is what is null, but I don't know enough to know how to cure it? When I hover over it I get: Model = Specie = null. Any idea what might be the source?

Comment: @MelB don't worry about it, you are on the right track. Basically you have forgotten to initialize it. Now I do not know what exactly you need, because I know too little about your expectations. But. If it's "normal" not to initialize it for some reason, then you could simply define it as a property with a default, like `public int? SpecieId { get; set; } = -1;`. You can choose some other default if you prefer. See https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/set-default-value-to-property-in-csharp?utm_content=cmp-true

Comment: @MelB if you intend something different, then you might decide to provide further information. It all depends on what you intend to do.

Comment: The SpecieId is a foreign key too, so I'm not sure if this is causing an issue? Maybe I am missing something to make that work correctly?

Comment: @MelB you need to have the value of the option being equal to the id of the specie and the inner text needs to be the name. But to fix the problem, you need to wrap an if around your option template and check for anything that could be null to differ from null, so your option will only be displayed if it's not damaged and your problem will not exist.

Comment: @MelB is `Model` null?

Comment: When I hover over the highlighted area and click on the link, it says 'Case' is null. The error message also says RabiesShotTracker1.Pages.Cases.EditModel.Case.get returned null.

Comment: @MelB if you (temporarily) remove your `for` loop, do you still get an exception?

Comment: If I remove the for loop, it goes past that point with no issue and stops at the next dropdown and returns exactly the same issue for that dropdown. There are 4 dropdowns that are set up the same way. Basically, 4 small supporting tables that feed the dropdown choices to the main table.

Comment: @MelB so, your issue is that `Model.Case` is `null`. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what it should look like so I am understanding correctly? My Case model does NOT contain the SpeciesName, so I cannot compare that to the SpeciesName in item1 without getting errors: error CS1061: 'Specie' does not contain a definition for 'SpeciesId' and no accessible extension method 'SpeciesId' accepting a first argument of type 'Specie' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 'Case' does not contain a definition for 'SpecieName' and no accessible extension method 'SpecieName'...

Comment: Yes, Model.Case is null.

Comment: @MelB what is `Model.Case` expected to be?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It is a table that contains rabies case details. Ie, what did the biting, where it happened, etc.

Comment: I have added the complete top of my Edit.schtml page just in case something is off there.

Comment: @MelB this means that at the line of `Case = _db.Case.Find(Id);` the case was not found by an `Id` search. Either you should never have a `null` for `Case` in which case it's possible that the problem is related to your stored data or, it can legitimately be `null` and you need to handle that special case. The solution depends on the answer to this question.

Comment: Can you give me some idea of what I should be looking for? I'm at a complete loss at this point. What do you mean "never have a null for Case"? I have all fields set to nullable except for the Key itself.

Comment: @MelB so is it okay if `Case` is `null`? If so, do you want to display options for it? If so, what would you default its value?

Comment: @MelB I have added a possible solution to my answer. Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code as you noted. I am now able to open the Edit.cshtml page without error, but none of my data is there. It is just an empty page. So, I am missing something that is letting me read the Case Model. I just have no idea what (as I am very new to this and have no formal training, only online tutorials). The Case model/table does have data in it, so there should are NOT any actual nulls in the data that is there. I just don't understand why the Case table cannot be read?

Comment: The Edit page is used to update/make any changes to the record the user created with the Create page. So the values created on the Create page should display on the Edit page (including the choices that they selected in the dropdowns), but they do not.

Comment: If I try to edit the page, I get a validation error: The value '' is invalid. I have looked this error up, but cannot find anything else to make nullable to cure it?

Comment: @MelB currently I do not have a .NET environment to look into this (I've not worked with .NET since 2020), but, if you have an edit page and the case is `null` even though it has a proper value in the database, then it seems to be a problem either with hydration (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data), which you may need to set to eager or to explicit, or, the other possible problem is that the case might be not passed by the action. Try passing a hard-coded, "whatever" case from the action for now and see whether it's null on the view.

Comment: Can you please elaborate: Try passing a hard-coded, "whatever" case from the action for now and see whether it's null on the view. I'm sorry, I do not understand how to do that. I read the link you provided, but do not have enough background knowledge to understand exactly where to put the code (assuming OnGet) or if when I add code, I need to remove some of my existing code?

Comment: @MelB the suggestion was to simply pass a `Case` to the view with hard-coded value so that we make sure that the `Case` is properly passed to the view. Furthermore: is `_db.Case.Find(Id)` returning a proper case?

Comment: OK. We're onto something! I changed Case = _db.Case.Find(Id); to Case = _db.ICase.Find(Id = 1); and when I ran the program, it loaded the Edit.cshtml page, AND displayed the correct data for record #1 in the database Case table!!! So, I'm not sure what the correct code to use to help the program find ANY record in the Case table. Can you help with that, if possible, please?

Comment: @MelB this means that the problem all along was that the Id is not properly received by OnGet. You will need to look into how it is being triggered.